# Cargar react-select desde una api con axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Estoy usando el componente **react-select** consumiendo datos desde una api-rest. La consulta y el retorno de los datos funciona correctamente. Sin embargo, falla lo siguiente **la carga de los options en el select**

Mi codigo desarrollado es el siguiente, desde el html lo llamo así:

```
<AsyncSelect cacheOptions defaultOptions loadOptions={this.loadRepuestos} />
```

Luego tengo mi code de la funcion **loadRepuestos** que es el siguiente:

```
loadRepuestos = (name) => {
  if(name.length > 3 && this.state.peticionActiva !== true) {
    const config = {
      headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${this.state.token['token']}` }
    };

    let url = API_REPUESTOS_FILTER + `?name=${name}`;
    // console.log(this.state.token['token']);
    this.setState({peticionActiva: true});
    //seteo peticionActiva true para evitar que se desaten continuas peticiones
    return  axios.get(url,config)
        .then(response => {
            this.setState({peticionActiva: false});

            let lista = response.data.data;
            //armo el par {{value ... label.. } ......}
            let options = lista.map(elemento => {
                let item = {};
                item.value = elemento.id;
                item.label = elemento.name;

                return item;
            });

            console.log(options);
            // console.log({options: options});
            return {options: options};
        })
        .catch(e => {
          this.setState({peticionActiva: false});
          if(e.response)
          {
              let error = '';
              error = e.response.data.message;
              console.log(error);
              // this.setState({errorApi: error});
          }
        });
  }
}
```

Imprimiendo en la consola, los datos viene y se ve como lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pude resolver el problema! Me di cuenta que cuando arma el mapeo de los pares [ {id,label} ..... ] el id me quedaba en **formato de nro** y no en **string**.

Por lo tanto modifique mi mapeo de como estaba:

```
let options = lista.map(elemento => {
            let item = {};
            item.value = elemento.id;
            item.label = elemento.name;

            return item;
        });
```

A la siguiente forma:

```
 let options = lista.map(elemento => {    
      return { value:  `${elemento.id}`, label: `${elemento.name}` };
    });
```

Como puede verse en el code anterior, se cambio como se retorna el par {id,value} y se usa una interpolacion de string de ecmascript. En mi entorno uso babel y webpack, asi que eso se transpila automaticamente.

Parece loco que el paquete de react-select no haga un casteo automatico. Ahora en adelante lo voy a tener en cuenta porque es una falla dificil de encontrar.

Answer (score 1):

Lo mapeaste¡? se ven los datos, pero el select necesita un mapeo. Yo lo cargo en otro componente funcional
const Options = ({ id,label}) =>{
  return (               )}

Comment: Te refieres a modificar el map que ejecuto en la clausula them?

Comment: En el return { id , value }